# Filtering a Million Records to 100,000 from two different sources

Tags: sql, excel, vba, filter

I have a project where I want to automate the reporting of a stupidly large set of data in Excel VBA. Basically I have a 1,000,000+ record database that I want to pull ~100,000 records from. The only way I have the 100,000 items is in an excel sheet, and I can't dump it into the same database to filter or into a temp table on the same server. 
Is there a way to treat the Excel spreadsheet values as a database and call it within the SQL query in the VBA? I'd prefer not to use a loop because the database response is already poor enough as it is.

Ideas?

Thanks.

Edit - My assumption of "looping being bad" is incorrect according to one comment. Is this true? Would looping through the ID's have to poll the database 100,000 times or does it treat it as a single data pull?

Comment: I am not clear what you are trying to do: your title talks about 2 different data sources but your question only mentions 1 data source. Is what you are trying to do to join a 100K excel records with a 1000K records in a DB?

Comment: The Excel 100k list is one data source... The 1m records are in a DB2 database. The 100k IDs reside within the 1m records, and I'm looking for a way to just pull the 100K records from the DB2 recordset. I thought looping would be extremely taxing, but from the comments below I may be wrong. Any way that I can get the 100k IDs in the Excel Sheet from the 1m DB2 records without having to load all the records from DB2 into Excel is what I need to do.

Comment: I suggest a stored procedure in your db2 database that accepts a list of ID values as an input parameter.  Process the values as required in your db.  It will be tricky because you might run up against some sort of maximum allowable number.  Then run the appropriate query.  In vba, read the column with the id fields, call the stored procedure, and do something with the query results.

Comment: I can only query the DB2 database. I have no option to store anything in that database whatsoever. I'm limited to querying DB2 only. If I had access to make temp tables this would be easy.  Ugh. Maybe I'm just thinking about this in the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ADODB if you want to query within your workbook using sql like syntax.

I have included a sub to as an example of how to do this.  You could call said sub like below:

```vb
Call queryTable("select top 100000 * from [Sheet6$A1:AI31]", range("Sheet5!A1"))
```

This would query data located in the range `Sheet6$A1:AI31` (the first row being the headers) and would dump the data starting with the top left cell being `Sheet5!A1`.

```vb
Sub queryTable(sqlStr As String, destination As Range)
Dim strFile As String
Dim stADO As String
Dim cnt                 As ADODB.Connection
Dim recordcount         As Long
Dim fieldcount          As Long
Dim resultrange         As Range
Dim mydestination       As Range

strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName

'connection string may need to be altered a little bit depending on your excel version
stADO = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
                            & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection

'Running query
    With cnt
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Open stADO
        .CommandTimeout = 0
        Set rst = .Execute(sqlStr)
    End With

Set mydestination = destination.Cells(1, 1).Offset(1, 0)

'Copying data (not headers) to destination
mydestination.CopyFromRecordset rst

'Setting some important variables
recordcount = rst.recordcount
fieldcount = rst.Fields.Count

Set range_collection = Range(mydestination.Cells(1, 1).Offset(-1, 0),                  mydestination.Cells(1, 1).Offset(recordcount - 1, fieldcount - 1))

'Copying the headers
For i = 0 To fieldcount - 1
mydestination.Cells(1, 1).Offset(-1, i).value = rst.Fields(i).name
Next i


'Closing everything down
cnt.Close
Set cnt = Nothing


End Sub
```